# Azure DevOps build don't fail when coverage is below target with dotnet test

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps for a ASP.NET Core app, and a want use it with a criteria to approve a pull requests.

```
steps:
      - script: dotnet restore
        displayName: 'Run command: dotnet restore'

      - script: >
                dotnet test 
                /p:CollectCoverage=true 
                /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura 
                /p:Threshold=80 
                /p:ThresholdStat=total 
                /p:Exclude="[*xunit.*]*"
        displayName: 'Run command: dotnet test'
```

I want when code coverage (using coverlet) don't pass, the build fails. but despite the acceptance criteria do not pass, even a log message is generated, the step runs successfully.

> coverlet.msbuild.targets(41,5): error : The total line coverage is below the specified 80 coverlet.msbuild.targets(41,5): error : The total branch coverage is below the specified 80 coverlet.msbuild.targets(41,5): error : The total method coverage is below the specified 80

It's possible force a fail in this case?

Comment: Try to add `failOnStderr: true` in the dotent test task

Comment: i try, but it did not work. I think this message is not considered a failure.

Comment: In the logs the message is in red color or white color?

Comment: In my terminator console, red, but in azure devops console, white.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to run the tests with `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task and not with the simple `script`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    commands: test
    projects: 'path/to/tests/projects'
    arguments: 'p:CollectCoverage=true
 /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Threshold=80
 /p:ThresholdStat=total /p:Exclude="[*xunit.*]"'
```

Comment: sorry about my late, but this solution works fine, Thanks! My problem now is setting  different values for coverage criteria (branches, statements, lines, etc...) but this is another question :)

Comment: @NelsonBaggio Great :) you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Any idea how this same technic can be used in AppVeyor?

Comment: @JoyGeorgeKunjikkuru I don't know :/ I'm not familiar with AppVeyor

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, I got it working below is the blog post about the same https://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2020/02/failing-appveyor-build-on-low-test.html